# postgresql how to get min and max value from specific range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table of log finger print attendannce.

[image]

and i want to select the table with the result like this.

[image]

as you can see, in the mindailylog field, it contains the minumum date of that day, and the maxdailylog field value contains the max value of that day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       min(waktuabsen) over (partition by userid, waktuabsen::date),
       max(waktuabsen) over (partition by userid, waktuabsen::date),
from t;
```

This does the minimum *per* `user_id`.  If you want the overall minimum, just remove `userid` from the `partition by`.